# Classical field theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, variational-calculus

I am trying to find the equation of motion from the given action:
$$
S = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dt \int_{0}^{L} dx\left(\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi - \frac{m^2}{2}\phi \right)
$$
But, when doing $\delta S = 0$, I arrive at:
$$
\delta S = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dt \int_{0}^{L} dx\left(\partial_\mu \partial^\mu \phi (\delta \phi) - m^2 (\delta \phi) \right) = 0
$$
that leads me to a wrong answer. Can anyone help me understand where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The mass term is $m\phi^2/2$ you've missed the square. The calculation for the kinetic term seems correct. With $m\phi^2/2$ you'll obtain the Klein Gordon equation for a massive scalar field.

$$\Box \phi = m^2\phi$$